# How to mock viewModel when test controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, model-view-controller, identityserver3

I have to test my controller as below

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
[HandleError(View= "Error")]
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    return View("Index", new MyViewModel){
    Name = name,
    Link = Request.UrlReferrer
   }
}
```

and my ViewModel is as below

```
public class MyViewModel{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public Uri Link{get;set}
}
```

My problem is, when I write a unit test as below, the `controller.Index(name)` always return null, it seems because I didn't mock ViewModel? But how I mock the ViewModel as it is inside the function?

My purpose is to test if the name is passed into the ViewModel properly, I think I should not mock MyViewModel, is that correct?

Also, as this is HttpGet, should I mock the Http Request? I'm not sure how to test the Http Request in MVC.NET

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index_Return_ViewModel(){
    string name = "name";
    var controller = new MyController(foo, bar);

    var result = controller.Index(name) as ViewResult;
    var viewModel = controller.ViewData.Model as MyViewModel;

    Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
}
```

Comment: The code in the method under test is not accurate. May be a typo. please fix.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following example controller

```
public class MyController : Controller {

    [HandleError(View = "Error")]
    public ActionResult Index(string name) {
        return View("Index", new MyViewModel() {
            Name = name,
            Link = Request.UrlReferrer
        });
    }
}
```

for the purposes of explaining the answer.

Because the action accesses the `Request.UrlReferrer`, the unit test would need to provide the necessary dependencies for the test to be exercised to completion.

For example

```
[TestMethod]
public void Index_Return_ViewModel() {
    //Arrange
    var link = new Uri("http://example.com");
    var mockContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(_ => _.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer)
        .Returns(link);
    string name = "name";
    var controller = new MyController() {
        ControllerContext = mockContext.Object
    };

    //Act
    var result = controller.Index(name) as ViewResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);
    var viewModel = controller.ViewData.Model as MyViewModel;
    Assert.IsNotNull(viewModel);
    Assert.AreEqual(name, viewModel.Name);
    Assert.AreEqual(link, viewModel.Link);
}
```

There was no need to mock the view model. The action can be confirmed to behave as expected by comparing the returned model properties to the expected values.